# how to do group by and order by in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table one is 'tb_student' and other is 'tb_fees'

create query for 'tb_student'

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

create query for 'tb_fees'

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_fees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

In first table i am storing the student details and in other table storing the fees details

I want to select student details from 'tb_student' and last add fee from 'tb_fees' only for those student which are in class 6

so i tried this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tb_student s INNER JOIN
       tb_fees f on 
       s.email =f.email
 WHERE s.class = 6 GROUP BY s.email ORDER BY f.created_on DESC
```

This will give result only the first created how to get last created values

fees table

```
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (5,'ram@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-01 14:20:15');
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (6,'Sam@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-02 14:20:23');
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (7,'jak@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-03 14:20:30');
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (8,'Sam@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-29 14:20:35');
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (9,'ram@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-30 14:20:39');
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (10,'jak@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-30 14:36:13');
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (11,'rose@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-30 14:36:15');
insert into `tb_fees`(`id`,`email`,`amount`,`created_on`) values (12,'nim@gmail.com','5000','2013-05-30 14:36:15');
```

Student table values

```
insert into `tb_student`(`id`,`name`,`email`,`class`,`created_on`) values (5,'Ram','ram@gmail.com','6','2013-04-30 14:00:56');
insert into `tb_student`(`id`,`name`,`email`,`class`,`created_on`) values (6,'Sam','Sam@gmail.com','6','2013-03-30 14:01:30');
insert into `tb_student`(`id`,`name`,`email`,`class`,`created_on`) values (7,'Nimmy','nim@gmail.com','7','2013-04-30 13:59:59');
insert into `tb_student`(`id`,`name`,`email`,`class`,`created_on`) values (8,'jak','jak@gmail.com','6','2013-03-30 14:07:32');
insert into `tb_student`(`id`,`name`,`email`,`class`,`created_on`) values (9,'rose','rose@gmail.com','5','2013-04-30 14:07:51');
```

Thank you

Comment: give you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: Got any error in this?

Comment: It won't always give you the first created, although probably will. Which one it gives you is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the latest fees something like this:-

```
SELECT s.* , f.*
FROM tb_student s 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT email, MAX(created_on) AS created_on
    FROM tb_fees
    GROUP BY email) Sub1
ON s.email = sub1.email
INNER JOIN tb_fees f 
ON s.email = f.email AND Sub1.created_on = f.created_on
WHERE s.class = 6
```

By the way, you probably want indexes on the email fields (or better, use the tb_student id field on the tb_fees table instead of the email field and index it)

Comment: two inner join it will take time to execute

Comment: Joins take virtually no time to execute if indexed properly (hence the index suggestion). But doing this or equivalent is pretty much the only way to get the results you require in a single SQL call (and multiple calls would be FAR slower).

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX group function

```
SELECT s.*, f.amount,MAX(f.created_on)
FROM tb_student s 
  INNER JOIN
     tb_fees f 
  ON 
     s.email =f.email
WHERE s.class = 6  
GROUP BY s.email
```

Comment: it will show all the remaining fields also from tb_fees table

Comment: The original didn't work as it brought back the latest fee date, but the other fee details will be random ones for that student. With the edited version I can't see how it will work using HAVING like that.

Comment: Please read this http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html to understand why your usage of the group by clause is **wrong** and will be rejected by every other DBMS.

Comment: It is not working. With you test date change the fee amounts to be different on each row and this will probably become obvious.

Comment: amount value its taking first created

Comment: The one it takes is undefined. It may well be the first one, but this is not certain and MySQL could return any of the amounts.